# Why does my android app build locally but fails with Github Actions?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I have a project that compiles fine when I run `ANDROID_HOME=/.../Library/Android/sdk gradle clean assembleDebug`. But when I try to run the same on a github action like this...

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'
jobs:
  test:
    name: Analyze Android
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout App
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          distribution: temurin
          java-version: 11
      - name: Setup Gradle
        uses: gradle/gradle-build-action@v2
      - name: Setup Android SDK
        uses: android-actions/setup-android@v2
      - name: Assemble
        run: |
          ./gradlew clean assembleDebug
```

I get

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:mergeDebugAssets'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :DTO.
     Required by:
         project :app
         project :app > project :UI
         project :app > project :Data
         project :app > project :Domain
      > No matching configuration of project :DTO was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.2.1', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm' but:
          - None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
```

But the DTO project does exist and as I said works locally. I checked the versions and they look to be the same...

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-08-05 21:17:56 UTC
Revision:     d1daa0cbf1a0103000b71484e1dbfe096e095918

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          15.0.2 (Oracle Corporation 15.0.2+7-27)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.16 x86_64
```

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 7.5.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2022-08-05 21:17:56 UTC
Revision:     d1daa0cbf1a0103000b71484e1dbfe096e095918

Kotlin:       1.6.21
Groovy:       3.0.10
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          11.0.16 (Eclipse Adoptium 11.0.16+8)
OS:           Linux 5.15.0-1014-azure amd64
```

Why does it work locally but not via Github Actions?

### Updates

It looks like it is because the library is setup like this...

```
plugins {
    id 'java-library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm'
}
```

instead of like the rest...

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
```

So it finds the others but not this one. But I tried converting to an android app and I get the same issue.

Comment: Hello @Jackie, did you find the solution for the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it was because my local box was OSX (not case sensitive) and the build box was Ubuntu (case sensitive). Once the name was lowercased it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think your computer doesn't have enough space(RAM) for Build. I also faced the similar issue but it got resolved when I Increased my internal ram.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).